# DefaultManifestParser deprecated in AGP 7, what's the replacement

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I was using `com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser` to get `versionName` in `build.gradle` earlier.
Then I updated my android gradle plugin to `7.0.1` and with this update `DefaultManifestParser` is deprecated. Moreover, it doesn't have a method to get `versionName` anymore.
Here's the commit https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/7b2eb3d92dfa29f8cb01cec47f48e18d5b2eb70b that removes `getVersionName` and `getVersionCode` method. A later [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/a3cc13099255203710d7c7b1ffeda33e51bba236) deprecates the `DefaultManifestParser`.

The commit message mentions that

> With the new variant Api, we need all the values that
> can come fro the manifest to be using Provider<> for
> their lazy mechanism

> This change introduces a parallel manifest parser that
> uses Provider to create a Provider
> which then can be mixed with the DSL values.

But I couldn't find the new way to get the versionName.

I did see that there's a new interface `VariantDslInfo` that has `versionName` whose class doc states

> Use [VariantDslInfoBuilder] to instantiate.

I checked the `VariantDslInfoBuilder` whose class doc states:

> Use [getBuilder] as an entry point.

But the `getBuilder` method expects a lot of arguments which I have no idea of, so I'm not sure how to use `VariantDslInfo` to get the versionName.

Furthermore, I'm not even sure if `VariantDslInfo` is supposed to be a replacement for `DefaultManifestParser` for providing the `versionName`.

So, to sum it all up, since `DefaultManifestParser` no longer works in AGP 7, what's the new way to get version name from `AndroidManifest` in `build.gradle`?